# Merging a geodataframe and pandas dataframe based on a column

Tags: merge, geopandas, python-3, pandas, concatenation

I have a simple `geopandas` dataframe that includes geometry and a column called `'MUKEY'`:

```
merged_spatial_df.head()
```

[image]

I want to merge it to a tabular (.csv) `pandas` dataframe (which also has a column called `'MUKEY'`) based on `'MUKEY'`.

```
merged_tab_df.head()
```

[image]
There are 31,000 rows in merged_spatial_df and about 391 in merged_tab_df, but each unique `MUKEY` value in merged_tab_df corresponds to one in merged_spatial_df. I tried the following but can't seem to merge them together and `.sjoin` requires 2 geodataframes. I tried:

```
merged_master = gpd.GeoDataFrame(merged_tab_df.merge(merged_spatial_df, how='right'))
```

but I got an error - `ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`, so I tried:

```
merged_master = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat([merged_tab_df, merged_spatial_df], join ='inner'))
```

None of the concats I tried produced viable results. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should specify **a common key** using `on` parameter. I removed `merged_` prefix for legibility.

```
df  = spatial_df.merge(tab_df, on='mukey', how='left')
# df  = tab_df.merge(spatial_df, on='mukey', how='right')
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df)
```

Sample `spatial_df`:

```
    col1 col2  mukey geometry
0   A    1.76  1     ...
1   B    0.40  2     ...
2   C    0.97  3     ...
3   D    2.24  4     ...
4   X    1.86  5     ...
5   Y    0.97  6     ...
```

Sample `tab_df`:

```
    col3 col4  mukey
0   100  0.95  2
1   200  0.15  3
2   300  0.10  4
```

Result:

```
    col1  col2  mukey geometry  col3   col4
0   A     1.76  1     ...       NaN    NaN
1   B     0.40  2     ...       100.0  0.95
2   C     0.97  3     ...       200.0  0.15
3   D     2.24  4     ...       300.0  0.10
4   X     1.86  5     ...       NaN    NaN
5   Y     0.97  6     ...       NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Adding 'on'='MUKEY' and 'how'='left' did thie trick!

Comment: @gwydion93 `'how'='left'` is not the trick. I editted the question.

Comment: This is what I used that worked; similar, but not exactly the same: `merged_master = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.merge(merged_tab_df, merged_spatial_df, on="MUKEY", how="right"))`